# Do math operations to output from COUNT and GROUP BY statemetns

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

Suppose I have a Yes/No data column. Then I can count the observations in each outcome category by

```
Select MyVar, count(MyVar) from MyTable
group by MyVaR;
```

The output is someting like:

```
MyVar    count(MyVar)
Yes               10
No                5
```

How can I add another element to this outputtable which is the fraction (Yes/No) so my final table is something like:

```
MyVar    count(MyVar)
Yes               10
No                5
Fraction          2
```

**Is there a simple solution to this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by grouping sets()` for that:

```sql
Select 
   case 
      when grouping(MyVar)=0 then MyVar
      else 'Fraction'
   end grouping_value,
   case 
      when grouping(MyVar)=0 then count(MyVar) 
      else count(decode(MyVar,'Yes',1)) / count(decode(MyVar,'No',1))
   end c
from MyTable
group by grouping sets(MyVaR,())
```

Full test case with sample data:

```sql
with MyTable(MyVar) as (
  select * 
  from table(sys.odcivarchar2list(
               'Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes',
               'No','No','No','No','No'
            ))
)
Select 
   case 
      when grouping(MyVar)=0 then MyVar
      else 'Fraction'
   end grouping_value,
   case 
      when grouping(MyVar)=0 then count(MyVar) 
      else count(decode(MyVar,'Yes',1)) / count(decode(MyVar,'No',1))
   end val
from MyTable
group by grouping sets(MyVaR,())
;
```

Results:

```sql
GROUPING_VALUE         VAL
--------------- ----------
No                       5
Yes                     10
Fraction                 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simplest -- in this format -- using `union all`:

```
with t as (
      Select MyVar, count(MyVar) as cnt
      from MyTable
      group by MyVaR
     )
select MyVar
from t
union all
select 'Ratio', sum(case when MyVar = 'Yes' then cnt else 0 end) / sum(case when MyVar = 'No' then cnt else 0 end)
from t;
```

That said, I would just use conditional aggregation and put all values in a single row:

```
select sum(case when MyVar = 'Yes' then cnt else 0 end) as yes,
       sum(case when MyVar = 'Yes' then cnt else 0 end) as no,
       sum(case when MyVar = 'Yes' then cnt else 0 end) / sum(case when MyVar = 'No' then cnt else 0 end) as ratio
from t;
```